# some jQuery/JavaScript to change bgcolor on input checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, I want some jQuery/JavaScript to show an yellow `background-color` when its checked. I use `class="valgt"` to define which `checkbox` I want to be styled.

How do I do this?

```
<td valign="top" class="valgt"> 
    <input  type="checkbox" name="check" value="" /> 
</td>
```

I have no idea how to fix it. So I need some code help for the jQuery/JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  It would be easier if you put an ID or name on your td.

```
$('input[name=check]').click(function() {
    var chkbox = $(this);
    if (chkbox.is(':checked'))
        chkbox.parent().addClass('valgt');
    else
        $chkbox.parent().removeClass('valgt');
});
```

Comment: wow! thx alot, that worked just fine. no prob at all! 

I appreciate your help! :)

Comment: as a general rule beware of excessive creation of jQuery objects e.g $(this). Do it once and cache it.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your bg color in the css class

```
.valgt { background-color : #ffff00; }
```

then use the following to add or remove this class from the parent td dependent on the checked state

```
$('input[name=check]').click( function(){

   var $el = $(this);
   $el.is(':checked') ? $el.parent().addClass('valgt') 
                      : $el.parent().removeClass('valgt');

})
```